# How to dynamically enable/disable Tornado Auth on Python script?

Tags: python, tornado

I would like to have a Python script that start the Tornado. I would like to like to enable auth only on the production stage and disable auth during development stage.

```
# This is the main page handler
class MainPageHandler(BaseHandler):
    def get(self):
        if not self.get_current_token():
            self.redirect(self.reverse_full_url("tokenLogin"))
            return
        self.render('index.html')

# This is the main tornado app
class Application(tornado.web.Application):
  def __init__(self, disableAuth=False):
    ...

# This is running in main function
Application(disableAuth).listen(PORT, HOST)
```

Would it be possible that I could switch on/off auth using python argument? An example would be very very nice.

Thanks in advance

Comment: You can check if `debug` is true or false from a handler method like this: `self.application.settings.get('debug')`. Now you can disable/enable auth depending on this value.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Currently I would use a global flag (a flag in the config file) to take care of passing the variable around.

Answer (score 1):

The `Application` object is available as an attribute on `RequestHandler` objects, so as long as you set the `self.disableAuth` attribute in your `Application.__init__`, you can do something like this in your handler:

```
def get(self):
    if not self.application.disableAuth:
        # auth goes here...
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are using the built-in support for user authentication and require a user object for downstream operations, you could add the authorization check to the `get_current_user` like so:

```
class BaseHandler(tornado.web.RequestHandler):
    def get_current_user(self):
        if self.application.settings.disableAuth:
             return self.get_debug_user()  # A method that returns a debug user.
        else:
             return self.get_authenticated_user()  # Performs your actual authentication and returns the real user object.

class MainPageHandler(BaseHandler):
    def get(self):
        if not self.current_user:
            self.redirect(self.reverse_full_url("tokenLogin"))
            return
        self.render('index.html')
```